# Add parameter in function signature in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, function, parameter-passing

What should I do the the function signature below to add one more parameter:

```
- (void)locationPondSizeViewController:
(LocationPondSizeViewController *)controller 
                   didSelectPondSize:(NSString *)thePondSize
{
    ....
}
```

its actually a delegate function and called from:

```
[self.delegate locationPondSizeViewController:self 
                              didSelectPondSize:thePondSize];
```

Also help me to understand what is delegate name, function name, parameters, and return type in this signature.

Comment: Just append `parameter1:(id)parameter1 parameter2:(id)parameter2` to the method name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a bit like a homework question...

The Objective-C declaration:

```
- (void)locationPondSizeViewController:(LocationPondSizeViewController *)controller 
                     didSelectPondSize:(NSString *)thePondSize { ... }
```

would be written in a language using more traditional style declarations as:

```
void locationPondSizeViewController:didSelectPondSize:(LocationPondSizeViewController *controller, NSString *thePondSize) { ... }
```

(though most languages don't allow :'s in an identifier)

So the method/function name is `locationPondSizeViewController:didSelectPondSize:`, it takes two parameters of types `LocationPondSizeViewController *` and `NSString *` and returns nothing (`void`), i.e. its a procedure. The parameters are referred to in it's body as `controller` and `thePondSize`.

You extend for further parameters by adding " <part of name>:(<type>)<parameter name>" as many times as you need.

Pointless tidbit: You actually do not need to precede the colons with anything, this is a valid definition of the method `::`:

```
- (int) :(int)x :(int)y { return x + y; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of your method with an additional parameter added:

```
- (void)locationPondSizeViewController:(LocationPondSizeViewController *)controller 
                     didSelectPondSize:(NSString *)thePondSize
                      withNewParameter:(NSObject*)newParam
{
    ...
}
```

And here's how you would call it:

```
[self.delegate locationPondSizeViewController:self didSelectPondSize:thePondSize withNewParameter:myParam];
```

In this example the method signature is `- locationPondSizeViewController:didSelectPondSize:withNewParameter:`

It takes three parameters: 1) `controller`, 2) `thePondSize`, and 3) `newParam`

The return type of this method is `void`.

Comment: This is perfect. Firdous, notice that he's not putting a return after `locationPondSizeViewController:` and before `(LocationPondSizeViewController *)controller`, which makes it hard to read. If you'd rather, you can also put the entire method signature on one line with a space between each part.